# How can I get a Bluetooth keyboard input event in Android?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, keyboard

I would like to give specific events when typing Bluetooth keyboard.

My app is always running as a service.

When you input a key with Bluetooth keyboard, the following log is recorded.

```
/? I / WCNSS_FILTER: do_write: IBS write: fc
/? I / WCNSS_FILTER: Direction (1): bytes: 19: bytes_written: 19
/? D / InputReader: Input event (15): value = 1 when = 586669729008000
/? I / InputDispatcher: Delivering key to (1099): action: 0x0 (0)
/? D / ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0
/? D / SecContentProvider2: query (), uri = 15 selection = getToastEnabledState
/? D / SecContentProvider2: query (), uri = 15 selection = getToastShowPackageNameState
```

Is there a way to get the call to 'InputReader: Input event' from the service?
or should I use another method?